# urllib2.urlopen hangs when invoked by apache server

Tags: python, apache, urllib2

I have a python script that reads a resource using urllib2 like so

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
html = response.read()
response.close()
```

which works fine when invoked in a terminal.  However, when invoked by an apache server, it just hangs on the urlopen.  Any ideas why that is?

Edit:  FWIW, there's no change in behavior if I spoof a mozilla user agent, or pass an empty dict for proxy handlers

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: How do you invoke it with Apache? Also, how can you be sure `urlopen()` causes the hang? Might be the hand-back to Apache that hangs?

Comment: just by pointing a browser to the script.
I added tracers that show that it's the urlopen line that hangs

Comment: does `urllib.urlopen` works? Can you try it instead of `urllib2`?

Comment: This has the same behavior

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find the reason for this?